# Callback function in plugin

Tags: jquery, callback

I am trying to write my first plugin in jQuery, and I am a little bit  confused with the callbacks.

For me, it's seems that everything is fine, but surly it is not.

The logic is (what I supposed) is to create a global `settings` object. When instantiate the `tokenizer` settings will be extended / overwrote with given settings / options, so it should be override the `onAdd` here `$('#xxx').tokenizer(...`

After that I just `add` an item, but in the console it sad:

```
The item in onAdd
undefined
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzukr516/)

```
var settings = {
    onAdd: function () {},
    onRemove: function () {},
    sourceSelecter: null,
    targetSelector: null
};

$.fn.tokenizer = function (options) {
    this.settings = $.extend({
        targetSelector: this,
        idName: 'id'
    }, settings, options);

    this.add = function (item) {
        console.log('The item in function add: ' + item);
        this.settings.onAdd.call(item);
    };

    this.remove = function (item) {
        this.settings.onRemove.call(item);
    };

    return this;
};

var $tokenizer = $('#xxx').tokenizer({
    sourceSelector: 'group',
    onAdd: function (item) {
        console.log('The item in onAdd');
        console.log(item);
    }
});

$tokenizer.idName = 'groupId';
$tokenizer.add('abcdefg');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call` should be:-

```
this.settings.onAdd.call(this, item);
```

> **Syntax**
>
> `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rzukr516/1/)

Comment: Cool, it works, thank you. I did not read perceptive enough the arguments. When SO timer will allow me to accept answer, I will.

Comment: glad I could help.